# Best way to implement dynamic array of inputs in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently I have implemented it using plain javascript array. But there seems to be few problems.

1. `onChange`, `onDelete` has to iterate all over the array which could be better like O(1)
2. When some item gets deleted key property of other items get changed. I'm not sure if it's bad or not.

Using `immutable.js` can get rid of problem 1. Is number 2 really a problem? Is there a better alternative than `immutable.js`?
Maybe I'm not asking the right questions, what's the best way?

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function() {
    const [rows, setRows] = useState([""]);

    const onChange = (e, i) => {
        setRows(rows.map((row, index) => (index !== i ? row : e.target.value)));
    };

    const onDelete = i => {
        setRows(rows.filter((_, index) => i !== index));
    };

    return (
        <>
            {rows.map((row, index) => {
                return (
                    <div key={index}>
                        <input value={row} onChange={e => onChange(e, index)} />
                        {index !== 0 && (
                            <button onClick={() => onDelete(index)}>
                                - delete row
                            </button>
                        )}
                    </div>
                );
            })}

            <button onClick={() => setRows(rows.concat([""]))}>
                + add row
            </button>
        </>
    );
}
```

**UPDATE**

I tried using `immutable-js` `OrderedMap`. Now `key` property of elements won't change and `onChange` and `onDelete` won't iterate over everything. Is this better than before?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { OrderedMap } from "immutable";

export default function() {
    const [inputState, setInputState] = useState({
        rows: OrderedMap(),
        nextKey: Number.MIN_VALUE,
    });

    function onChange(k, v) {
        setInputState({
            ...inputState,
            rows: inputState.rows.update(k, () => v),
        });
    }

    function addRow() {
        const { rows, nextKey } = inputState;
        setInputState({
            rows: rows.set(nextKey, ""),
            nextKey: nextKey + 1,
        });
    }

    function deleteItem(k) {
        setInputState({
            ...inputState,
            rows: inputState.rows.delete(k),
        });
    }

    return (
        <>
            {inputState.rows.entrySeq().map(([k, v]) => {
                return (
                    <div key={k}>
                        <input
                            value={v}
                            onChange={({ target: { value } }) => {
                                onChange(k, value);
                            }}
                        />
                        <button onClick={() => deleteItem(k)}>-</button>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
            <button onClick={addRow}>+ add row</button>
        </>
    );
}
```

**UPDATE: 2**
Also tried using plain javascript `Map`.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function() {
    const [inputState, setInputState] = useState({
        rows: new Map(),
        nextKey: Number.MIN_VALUE,
    });

    function onChange(k, v) {
        const { rows, nextKey } = inputState;
        rows.set(k, v);
        setInputState({
            nextKey,
            rows,
        });
    }

    function addRow() {
        const { rows, nextKey } = inputState;
        rows.set(nextKey, "");
        setInputState({
            rows,
            nextKey: nextKey + 1,
        });
    }

    function deleteItem(k) {
        const { rows, nextKey } = inputState;
        rows.delete(k);
        setInputState({
            nextKey,
            rows,
        });
    }

    const uiList = [];

    for (const [k, v] of inputState.rows.entries()) {
        uiList.push(
            <div key={k}>
                <input
                    value={v}
                    onChange={({ target: { value } }) => {
                        onChange(k, value);
                    }}
                />
                <button onClick={() => deleteItem(k)}>-</button>
            </div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <>
            {uiList}
            <button onClick={addRow}>+ add row</button>
        </>
    );
}
```

**UPDATE 3**
Using plain array but with key property.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function() {
    const [inputState, setInputState] = useState({
        rows: [],
        nextKey: Number.MIN_VALUE,
    });

    function onChange(i, v) {
        const { rows, nextKey } = inputState;
        rows[i].value = v;
        setInputState({
            nextKey,
            rows,
        });
    }

    function addRow() {
        const { rows, nextKey } = inputState;
        rows.push({ key: nextKey, value: "" });
        setInputState({
            rows,
            nextKey: nextKey + 1,
        });
    }

    function deleteItem(i) {
        const { rows, nextKey } = inputState;
        rows.splice(i, 1);
        setInputState({
            nextKey,
            rows,
        });
    }

    return (
        <>
            {inputState.rows.map(({ key, value }, index) => {
                return (
                    <div key={key}>
                        <input
                            value={value}
                            onChange={({ target: { value } }) => {
                                onChange(index, value);
                            }}
                        />
                        <button onClick={() => deleteItem(index)}>-</button>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
            <button onClick={addRow}>+ add row</button>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, both diff check with immutable data using `pureComponent` or `React.memo()` and normal list operation in certain situation cost. You gonna need more specific condition for your optimization, otherwise normal way without anything else and simply use the default diff from react with origin js/ts is totally enough. As others have said which I want to refer: `never optimize too early`

Comment: How big the data is, i mean you array ?

Comment: I'm not sure about the array size, but I want it to be as fast as possible

Comment: Because the approach you should take also have a direct relation with data, if its a less amount of data below 10k or 20k rows plain js approach will be far enough.  Basically what i understood is you need to display each records and have delete and add row, When you click on the new it will create a new record, a new row.  I feel the normal plain js approach will be enough

Comment: @DulguunOtgon does application is slow while you perform the actions ?

Comment: Caution when using the array index as key. If you delete an item, another element will get that key and it could result in errors. https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: i think, This much is ok. React already do so many thing to optimize the tree. It wont refresh unless tree diff same. However, I can say u can smplify the map code to
const onChange = (v, i) => {
        rows[i] = v
        setRows([...rows]);
}

<input value={row} onChange={({target:{value}}) => onChange(value, index)} />

Comment: It's react, every state/prop update of an array will be an O(n) operation since you need to return a new array reference and copy old values. I'm sure there is no way around this. Don't use array index for react keys if you expect array elements to mutate over time.

Comment: I have added 3 other way. Not sure about which one would be most performant. See my updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, best choices are

1. Generate key to use as key.
2. Use map to have efficient update and delete.
3. Don't mutate the state.

The `immutable` library fits the point 2 and 3 perfectly. Since it can update and delete without mutation efficiently it seems like a good choice.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { OrderedMap } from "immutable";

function UsingImmutableJS({ onChange }) {
    const [inputState, setInputState] = useState({
        rows: OrderedMap(),
        nextKey: 0,
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        if (onChange) onChange([...inputState.rows.values()]);
    }, [inputState, onChange]);

    function onInputChange(k, v) {
        setInputState(prev => ({
            ...prev,
            rows: prev.rows.update(k, () => v),
        }));
    }

    function addRow() {
        setInputState(prev => ({
            nextKey: prev.nextKey + 1,
            rows: prev.rows.set(prev.nextKey, ""),
        }));
    }

    function deleteItem(k) {
        setInputState(prev => ({
            ...prev,
            rows: prev.rows.delete(k),
        }));
    }

    return (
        <>
            {inputState.rows.entrySeq().map(([k, v]) => {
                return (
                    <div key={k}>
                        <input
                            value={v}
                            onChange={({ target: { value } }) => {
                                onInputChange(k, value);
                            }}
                        />
                        <button onClick={() => deleteItem(k)}>-</button>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
            <button onClick={addRow}>+ add row</button>
            <button onClick={() => console.log([...inputState.rows.values()])}>
                print
            </button>
        </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using external js, i just do the little modification of the code, instead of doing the map or filter, you can use directly with splice,

the below code will help to do the deletion fast and it will keep the same index after deletion also.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function() {
    const [rows, setRows] = useState([""]);

    const onChange = (e, i) => {
      const {value} = e.target;
      setRows(prev => {
          prev[i] = value;
          return [...prev];
        });
    };

    const onDelete = i => {
        setRows(prev => {
          prev.splice(i,1, undefined);
          return [...prev];
        });
    };
    return (
        <>
            {rows.map((row, index) => (typeof row !== "undefined") && (
              <div key={index}>
                        <input value={row} onChange={e => onChange(e, index)} />
                        {index !== 0 && (
                            <button onClick={() => onDelete(index)}>
                                - delete row
                            </button>
                        )}
                    </div>
            ))}

            <button onClick={() => setRows(rows.concat([""]))}>
                + add row
            </button>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: But it still uses index as key. That's one problem I'm trying to avoid

Comment: So you want to remove data from the dynamic array without using index right ?

Comment: See my update 3. Figured out a way not to use index as keys while also using splice.

Comment: i updated my code in another  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60278323/1845830)

Answer (score -2):

Without index we can do using the Map and Map retrieval is faster, below code you can try.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function() {
    const [rows, setRows] = useState(new Map());

    const onUpdate = (key, value) => {
        setRows(prev => new Map(prev).set(key, { key, value}));
    }
    const onDelete = (key) => {
        setRows(prev => new Map(prev).delete(key));
    }
    return (
        <>
            {[...rows].map((row, index) => (typeof row[1].value !== "undefined") && (
                <div key={index}>
                    <input value={row[1].value} onChange={e =>  onUpdate(row[1].key, e.target.value)} />
                    <button onClick={() => onDelete(row[1].key)}>- delete row</button>
                </div>
            ))}

            <button onClick={() => onUpdate(rows.size, "")}>
                + add row
            </button>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: When you add and remove items the `Map` gets bigger and bigger holding lot of `undefined` values

Comment: Then you can use . delete to remove it. I just updated the code snippet. Now you won't get any undefined data